# Is this integral less than infinity?

Tags: convergence-divergence, computer-science, improper-integrals, turing-machines

Assume the following integral:

$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f\left(x\right)}
{BB\left(\lceil abs\left(x\right)\rceil\right)}\mathrm{d}x
$$

Where $f\left(x\right)$ is any computable function and $BB\left(n\right)$ is the busy beaver function.

Is there a function $f\left(x\right)$ which is everywhere less than $\infty$, but this integral equals $\infty$? I think such a function does not exist, but maybe i am wrong.

Thank you

Comment: How do you define computable functions in context of real numbers?

Comment: @Wojowu Presumably in the computable analysis sense; see http://eccc.hpi-web.de/resources/pdf/ica.pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: for $|x|$ large enough, we will have $BB(\lceil |x|\rceil)>f(x)\cdot x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

This integral is indeed always finite, at least for every notion of "computable function on $\mathbb{R}$" that I'm aware of.

Let $b(x)=BB(\lceil abs(x)\rceil)$ for short. It's enough to show that $b$ grows fast enough - that is, for every computable $g$ there is some $n$ such that $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, \quad\vert x\vert>n\implies b(x)>g(x).$$

The details of this proof will vary depending exactly what formalism you use.